# Tableau export chart not rendering full chart

Tags: javascript, pdf, tableau-api

I am currently working on exporting a chart to pdf using tableau javascript api, it's easy and straightfoward when using exportPDFDialog() function provided by tableau javascript api, but the problem is one of the charts has a vertical scroll bar to scroll down the data table below the chart and the scroll bar is also getting into the pdf instead of the entire chart, so in the end the chart that is displayed in the pdf has a scroll bar and only part of the data of the entire chart, so i would like to know if there is any work around.
I tried using the exportPDFDialog() provided by the javascript api[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [help docs](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/printing.htm) if you set the Print to PDF page size to Unspecified it should expand the image to the entire view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think that kinda did it, appreciate your help.